# Why is it bad to do things in if conditions

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

Today I discovered a code block in a code review that seamed weird to me but I could't find an objective reason why this code looks weird to me.

The code looks like this (it's PHP)

```
    // inside a for loop
    if( $thing->isGood() === true && saveThing($thing) ) {
      $successfulSavedCount++;
    }
    // for end

    function saveThing($thing) {
      // this method persists $thing to the database
    }
```

Checking if `$this->isGood() === true` is fine for me but calling a method that does something feels wrong to me.

A long time ago I read somewhere that **doing** things in conditions is bad style but I can't remember why it is bad style.

Maybe someone of you can explain why it is bad (or fine)?

Comment: This may help: [Why are side-effects considered evil in functional programming?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/15269/22659) (or not)

Comment: People use functions in if statements all the time and it is common practice in many situations. At best it be an opinion of whomever was reading the code according to their style documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most instances, doing *things* within a condition is just bad style, for it can be hard to read and maintain later on. There is nothing wrong with this though, as it is permitted by the language. The most convincing reason to avoid overly complicated condition statements are side effects. Consider the code below.

```
$globalVariable = true;    
....
if(checkVariable() && changeVariable()){
    do stuff....
}
function checkVariable(){
    return $globalVariable;
}
function changeVariable(){
    $globalVariable = false;
    return true; //Marking success
}
```

This if-statement would execute as the conditions, in order, are all true. But adding `&& checkVariable()` to the conditions would make it false, because of the side effect of `changeVariable()` modifying the behavior of `checkVariable()`. This then means `checkVariable()` holds two values, which is unintuitive and bad coding practice, but valid here. The rule of thumb is to have functions/methods execute before the condition and store the results in variable to use in the condition, to avoid the ambiguity.